# why Prefab displayed larger than default when apply Idle animation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, scale

uncheck animator:

[image]

after check animator:

[image]

the Animator:
[image]

the Block Prefab with Animator:
[image]
when i drag one block to other same number block,then trigger the merge animation, which scale up block and then scale to normal, but before apply merge animation, the block displayed larger than default when idle animation.

At first I doubt that the merge animation could result in the block bigger so i change the merge animation from scale up to down, but same result, the problem is that I have not triggered merge action!!!

the wierd is that the prefab will display normal size if it was located in hierarchy. if the prefab was created by C# code , it will displayed larger than normal size!!!

the scale of prefab created by c# code was equals to prefab that was located in hierarchy!!! Their values are equal to 1，but display size are different

[image]
[image]

I want to keep the same size of my prefab before apply merger animation when animator is in Idle state!!! appriciate any advise, please tell me how to keep the original size when gameobject in idle aniamtion

```
gameObject = GameObject.Instantiate(prefab, pos, rotate);
```

Comment: What is your animation doing? What does your hierarchy look like? Do you have any other scripts running?

Comment: @NSJacob1 Thanks for your reminder, I add some information

Comment: "the wierd is that the prefab will display normal size if it was located in hierarchy. if the prefab was created by C# code , it will displayed larger than normal size!!!"

Comment: Can't edit comment on mobile it seems...

Comment: When you instantiate through C#, do you see different scale or position values on that object in the inspector, compared to one you placed in the scene from the project window?

Comment: @NSJacob1 the sacle is same and equals to 1,but display size are different, I supply some image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with adding them directly to game. Not in Window in game, GamePanel as child.

Comment: the display is larger than normal size if add them directly to game, which is not i want, i want the display size is same as normal that the special one in window game

Comment: When I uncheck animator, the size is correctly, but when check animator, the size of display is larger than uncheck animator. The blocks in the window are just for reference，that is what i want, Block_x_x_(num) is created by C# code,but display error, the block in window game, display right, why?

Comment: I said it because I wondered if it going to work when you add the objects direcly game with c#. If it spawned with regular size it could help to solution.

Comment: All blocks are created by C# :Block block = PrefabFactory.Spawn<Block>(prefabs.block, pos, Quaternion.identity);
            block.transform.SetParent(gamePanel.transform);

Comment: Maybe because of size of GamePanel or WindowInGame. If it is bigger than 1 than it is normal to display larger.

Comment: You are right! I find that the scale of GamePanel is 1.333. I setup scale to 1, then the displayed size was normal, but if the Prefab uncheck animator, and even though the scale of GamePanel is 1.333, the prefab display size is also normal ?

Comment: I think when you normally animating child unity adds the animator component to parent. But when you add it with c# as a child animator is still being in added object. And parent's size effects the child's size. I am not sure but I think it is kind a bug.